# Access a JSON key from env variable

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

Im using ubuntu to store JSON-encoded text into a environment variable like this:

```
~ test='{"test": { "mmm":"432"}}'
~ echo $test
{"test": { "mmm":"432"}}
```

how can i access the key `"test"` to print `{"mmm":"432"}`?

something like

```
~ test='{"test": { "mmm":"432"}}'
~ echo $test.test
{ "mmm":"432"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't have json support. You must use a command line `jq` to process the output.

For example:

`echo "$test" | jq .test`

Answer (score 1):

https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ is your friend.

Simply use `echo "$test" | jq .test`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$test` is really an (exported) "environment variable", you can use jq's `env` or `$ENV` builtins to access it, avoiding the `echo` subshell:

```bash
jq -n 'env.test | fromjson.test'
# or
jq -n '$ENV.test | fromjson.test'
# or
jq -n 'env["test"] | fromjson.test'
# or
jq -n '$ENV["test"] | fromjson.test'
```

```json
{
  "mmm": "432"
}
```